# GWT: How to set the style of a HTML Element / First Paramter of HTML.setStylePrimaryName?

Tags: gwt

I have

```
HTML test = new HTML( "myhtml" );
```

which generates

```
<div class="gwt-HTML">MyHTML</div>
```

I want to set the primary style using this:

```
HTML.setStylePrimaryName(null, "mystyle");
```

What must be the first Paramter? Null is not working.

Comment: pass it 'test', it is the element to which you want to apply the style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIObject.setStylePrimaryName` static method is for when you have to work with `Element`s (you'll also note that it's `protected`, it really is an implementation detail of widgets and other *UI objects*).

You'd want to use the `setStylePrimaryName` instance method:

```
test.setStylePrimaryName("mystyle");
```

But actually, most of the time, you'd better use [`addStyleName`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#addStyleName%28java.lang.String%29), to keep the `gwt-HTML` class name around (or in the case of a `TextBox` for instance, keep the `gwt-TextBox` and `gwt-TextBox-readonly`; if you change the *primary name* to `mystyle`, you'll then have `mystyle-readonly` **instead** of `gwt-TextBox-readonly`, it is sometimes desirable, but most of the time it's not):

```
text.addStyleName("mystyle");
```

Comment: The instance Method setStylePrimaryName seems to not exist for HTML ?

Comment: Ups, got it. HTML is not my variable name. It is a class name. I was blind.